# Unix shell script - How to use a variable value within [for .. in `find .... <variable value>`] statement

Tags: datetime, for-loop, variables, unix, find

I need to loop over the list of file names that have been modified after a specif datetime value, that has been previously defined into a variable.

The following piece of code works well, but unfortunately it has the datetime value hardcoded inside it and is not defined in a previous variable.

```
for s in `find /prod/bin -type f -newermt '9/11/2020 15:09:00'`
do
    echo $s   
done
```

On the other hand, I need  first of all to define a datetime variable and next use its value inside the code.
I tried with the following code but it doesn't work. Can anyone explain to me what's wrong?

```
my_datetime_value=$(date "+%m/%d/%Y %H.%M.%S")
for s in `find /prod/bin -type f -newermt '$(my_datetime_value)'`
do
    echo $s    
done
```

Thank you a lot Stackoverflow  !!
Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use double quotes:

```
my_datetime_value=$(date "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
for s in `find /prod/bin -type f -newermt "$my_datetime_value"`
do
    echo $s    
done
```

Comment: I tried but unfortunatelly the following error is raised:  "I cannot figure out how to interpret "09/12/2020 13.31.58" as a date or time"

Comment: Use ":" while defining my_datetime_value, I have updated my comment